# html() , append() is not working on elements coming through ajax call, remove is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, grails

here id the div where my ajax cal content will display

```
<div class="topics"></div>
```

here is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        data : {
            q : typedString
        },
        url : "/parent/childAjax?hideList=" + hideList,
        success : function(msg) {
            if (msg != '') {
                $(".topics").html(msg).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

here is backend code in childAjax action

```
.......
......
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(); 
output.append("<li><a href='#' onclick='addTopic(this.id)' class='catClass ${count%2==0?'odd':'even'} ui-link'  id='${document.uniqueId}'>")
                    output.append("${document.name}")
                    output.append("</a>")
output.append("<span id='tick-${document.uniqueId}'><img src='${resource(dir:'images/mobile',file:'plus-icon.png')}' alt='' style='width:16px; height:16px' /></span></li>")
```

what actually i need to do is when i click on `<a>` element my js function is being called and in that i am replacing image plus-icon.png with other image  using .html("replacing image code"). some how its(.html()) not working.

here is response data sample...

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="addTopic(this.id)" class="catClass odd ui-link" id="551">Core Java</a><span id="tick-551"> <img src="http://192.168.0.105:8080/images/mobile/tick.png?v=0521" alt="" style="width: 16px; height: 16px"></span></li>

<li><a href="#" onclick="addTopic(this.id)" class="catClass even ui-link" id="776">Advanced JAVA</a><span id="tick-776"> <img src="http://192.168.0.105:8080/images/mobile/tick.png?v=0521" alt="" style="width: 16px; height: 16px"></span></li>
```

Comment: what is your response data ?

Comment: response is the data which i mentioned above under backend code. like below....here is a sample
<li><a href="#" onclick="addTopic(this.id)" class="catClass odd ui-link" id="551">Core Java</a><span id="tick-551"> <img src="http://192.168.0.105:8080/images/mobile/tick.png?v=0521" alt="" style="width: 16px; height: 16px"></span></li>

<li><a href="#" onclick="addTopic(this.id)" class="catClass even ui-link" id="776">Advanced JAVA</a><span id="tick-776"> <img src="http://192.168.0.105:8080/images/mobile/tick.png?v=0521" alt="" style="width: 16px; height: 16px"></span></li>

Comment: You need to debug it whether expected response is being received from the server and what data is geting pushed in th dom. I can not find the reason why this is not working..

Comment: @RayonDabre my apologies the issue is we are checking this in mobile. in desktop things are working fine. same methods are not working in mobile. we are jquerymobile 1.4.2. here also remove() is working html(), append() is not working

Comment: You can use chrome://inspect to debug your app in mobile devices..

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation. This will ensure the event is fired for elements that did not exist at DOM load. Bind to a static parent element (in this case the body).

```
$('body').on('click', '.catClass', function(){
     addTopic(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind events to dynamically loaded content via jQuery's $.live().

From jQuery http://api.jquery.com/live/:

Comment: "live()" has been deprecated .

Comment: use on instead of live, if you are using jquery 1.7+

Comment: @amit we are using mobile jquery 1.4. the issue is in mobile